# Override symfony make:entity to load custom columns

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

for the current project that I am going to work on, I need to create many entities using the make:entity command.

Each time a new entity is created it needs to have the following columns that need to be defined

- id_owner
- sys_date_created
- sys_date_modified
- date_created
- date_modified
- id_group
- id_user

The problem is that I will have to enter each of the following fields every time I create a new entity.

I have been looking at symfony and doctrine documentation if it is possible to override the make:entity function but to no avail.

What I would like is that each time we generate a new entity, the aboved mentioned fields are automatically generated.

For ex just the column id that is generated automatically by symfony.

If anyone has any working code or link to share that would be great.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Make a base abstract entity with these fields and then have the others extend it?

Comment: You could fork the maker bundle and then modify the entity template (Entity.tpl.php) file.  Might sound like overkill especially if you have not done this sort of thing before but it is a useful skill to have.  I have only peeked at the make bundle a few times but it seems like it should be possible to override where the template files live.  In which case it would be fairly easy to supply your own template.  But I don't see any current capability for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use an `MappedSuperclass` and extend it in your entities.

Example:

```php
/** @MappedSuperclass */
class Person {
   // define all shared properties

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $someProperty;
}
```

```php
/** @Entity */
class Employee extends Person {
   ...
}
```

This still enables you to use the maker bundle to create entities. However, after creating it, don't forget to extend the `MappedSuperclass` class.

In the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.12/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) you can find some more details about [inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.12/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) mapping.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for pointing that out. I added a link to the documentation.

Comment: MappedSuperClass also works with traits.  I kind of think that traits are better for these sorts of cross cutting concerns than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the maker bundle's Generator class and it turns out that there is a reasonable solution to override the templates being used.

The generator's code has:

```
       $templatePath = $templateName; // doctrine/Entity.tpl.php
        if (!file_exists($templatePath)) {
            $templatePath = __DIR__.'/Resources/skeleton/'.$templateName;

            if (!file_exists($templatePath)) {
                throw new \Exception(sprintf('Cannot find template "%s"', $templateName));
            }
        }
```

So when looking for a template file the generator first looks in the current directory and then in the maker bundle's Resources/skeleton directory.  So in your applications main directory make a directory called doctrine, copy in the default template file and edit to suit.  For example

```
# project_dir/doctrine/Entity.tpl.php
# Copy this from vendor/symfony/maker-bundle/Resources/skeleton/Entity.tpl.php
<?= "<?php\n" ?>

namespace <?= $namespace ?>;

<?= $use_statements; ?>

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: <?= $repository_class_name ?>::class)]
<?php if ($should_escape_table_name): ?>#[ORM\Table(name: '`<?= $table_name ?>`')]
<?php endif ?>
<?php if ($api_resource): ?>
#[ApiResource]
<?php endif ?>
<?php if ($broadcast): ?>
#[Broadcast]
<?php endif ?>
class <?= $class_name."\n" ?>
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    // Add your custom stuff here
    public function getWhatever() : void {}
}
```

After which the make:entity command will pick up your own custom template.  It is not a perfect solution.  If the maker bundle updates the template then you will need to update yours.  Also it would be nice if you could tell the generator where to look but it does work.

Comment: You are certainly welcome but be aware that stackoverflow frowns on these sorts of "thank you" comments and yours will be removed as soon as the bot gets around to it.  You have been presented with two solutions both of which seems to solve your question.  The way to indicate which solution works for you is to accept it.  If for some reason neither works then either post your actual solution (for future readers) or at least indicate why the posted answers are not suitable.